# the tree couldn't be instanced because the prefab contains no valid mesh renderer

Tags: unity

I am beginner in unity. The problem is when i installed a package tree from [Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/) then imported a tree, show me following message

**the tree couldn't be instanced because the prefab contains no valid mesh renderer**

so what the problem here and what should i do in this case ?

Comment: What "tree" package from what "website"?

Comment: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/45579

Comment: this package has most trees give a same message

Comment: Sounds like you didn't import the mesh.

Comment: which sounds ? how can i import the mesh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way for this error is

1. Click on this **Prefab**
2. Remove the mesh render for this **gameObject**
3. From **Inspector window** => **Add Component** => **Mesh Renderer**

Answer (score 0):

I was curious as to why it doesnt work for you. So i decided to try it.

- I am using Unity 5.3.4f1
- Downloaded the package
- Created a new scene
- added a new plane(made the plane a little bigger)
- went to UF Creator Lite->Prefabs->Trees
- in that folder there are 3 trees
- **drag and drop** each one to the plane

  and they should work after that.
  [image: 3 horses]